Twisting Arm issue
it's me again. So I have figured how to make sure my bones are skinned good which is a massive accomplishment for me however, I am having trouble with twisting wrists, I have tried to add some bones so they copy the rotation as I saw a tutorial on Youtube but that breaks my model so I have undone that, How do I fix this so that this models wrists doesnt twist badly as this? I have attached a file, Thank you guys so much, seriously life savers!
same thing happens when I try to rotate my Lower_Arm_L instead of the hand_L.

This is what I mean when I try to bend the wrist and the mesh deforms, again, not really sure what I'm doing with weight paints or anything I followed a Youtube tutorial to get me this far :D

Below is after removing the vertex groups that was advised, I still see a twist in the wrist?
I really am sorry guys, I am completely new to blender so Apologies, if I'm not seeing the mistake




hello, in what situation does it twist? In the shared file it isn't twisted, but the weight is not good, you need to reparent or correct the wight in Weight Paint mode

So when i use the hand_L and try to rotate it, the picture shows that it twists quite badly in pose mode, I'm not sure what I am doing with weight paint as I just skinned using automatic weights and it seemed to work, I also have this issue that with the bicep that it almost goes inside it self and a smooth arm bend isnt achieved, is there another tutorial for this? again, I do apologise, this is my first time using blender and creating projects :)

I have tried another method whereby I put 3 bones in the Lower_Arm_L and parent them as offset and when i put copy rotation the mesh breaks completely, Looks like Mr Elastic from fantastic 4

Did you check preserve volume on the armaturemodifier?

There are some uncorrect weight assignements (it happens frequently when using mirroring options during weight paint).
As you can read in the N properties panel, the active vertex on arm.R has some weights related to the Left Arm, leading to odd deformations.
To solve, select all vertices of the right arm and delete all weights related to Left arm, and vice-versa.


On my screen when I click exactly (I think) as you have I do not see that there are a mixture of Left in right and vise versa. I'm sorry, I'm new to blender

Try the procedure and see if it works: in Edit mode select all Right arm, go to Vertex groups Properties tab, select Lower_Arm.L vertex group and click Remove. Similar for Left Arm. The weights display is referred to the active vertex only (in multiple selections, the only one which is white), and only some of the vertices have this wrong assign.

After following the instructions I still have a twist in the arm but not as much as it was before. I have attached a picture :)
